# Have I got the syntax incorrect for this jquery else if statement?

Tags: jquery

Edit: **Question resolved. Syntax error.**

Here it is (the if part omitted as I know it is correct)

```
else if($('.now [name="stuff"]').val() !==''){...}
```

I want to check the value of the input field withhin the class 'now' and with the name 'stuff' and if the value is not empty, then execute the code within the braces.

have I made a mistake? as my code isn't working.

Edit here is the code in context: (NOTE - if i delete the else if part the code runs. Currently when I try to run the below code firefox tells me the function which contains the code is undefined)

```
if($("#form").length==0) {
           ....
    }
    else if($('.now [name="stuff"]').val() !==''){
    $.post("ajax.php", {
            "action": "refresh",
            "app_id": app,
            "type": type,
            "page": page,
            "test": "test";
            "refresh": "1",
            "br": $("#br").val(),
            "brtwo": $('.current [name="brtwo"]').val(),
        }, function(data) {
            $(".current").html(data);
            scrollTo(0, 0);
        });

    }
    else { ... 
     }
```

Comment: Found the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the space in the selector: `.now[name="stuff"]`

---

When written as `.now [name="stuff"]` it means: find elements with `class="now"` and then look within their children for elements with `name="stuff"`.

Comment: The space is intentional and finds the desired elements, I must have worded my question ambiguously.

Answer (score 0):

If I would be using your else if-statement on StackOverflow, I would be doing it like this:

```
else if( $('textarea.wmd-input[name="post-text"]').val() != '' ) { //do stuff }
```

Your snippet needs to remove the space between `.now` and `[name="stuff"]`, like this:

```
else if($('.now[name="stuff"]').val() !== ''){ //do stuff }
```

Hope this works out for you!